# Let $X,Y$ be two independent random variables and $P_X$, $P_Y$ are induced probability measure. Prove $P(X+Y\in B)=\int_{\Bbb{R}} P_Y(B-x)\ dP_X(x)$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X,Y$  be two independent random variables and $P_X$, $P_Y$ are induced probability measure. Prove $P(X+Y\in B)=\int_{\Bbb{R}} P_Y(B-x)\ dP_X(x)$

Here $P_X, P_Y$ are probability distribution of $X,Y$ respectively defined on $\mathcal{B}(\Bbb{R})$ as $P_X(B)=P(X\in B)$ and $P_Y(B)=P(Y\in B)$ for all $B\in\mathcal{B}(\Bbb{R})$.

My thoughts:

$\{\omega|\ X(\omega)+Y(\omega)\in B\}=\bigcup\limits_{x\in\Bbb{R}} \{\omega|\ Y(\omega)\in B-x\}\cap \{\omega|\ X(\omega)=x\}$

As $X, Y$ are independent, we have $P(\{\omega|\ Y(\omega)\in B-x\}\cap \{\omega|\ X(\omega)=x\})=P(Y\in B-x)=P(X=x)P(Y\in B-x, X=x)=P_Y(B-y)P_X(x)$

As $P(X+Y\in B)=P(\{\omega|\ X(\omega)+Y(\omega)\in B\})=P\left(\bigcup\limits_{x\in\Bbb{R}} \{\omega|\ Y(\omega)\in B-x\}\cap \{\omega|\ X(\omega)=x\}\right)$

Intuition says it has to be $P(X+Y\in B)=\int_{\Bbb{R}} P_Y(B-x)\ dP_X(x)$ but I'm unable to write it rigorously. If $X$ is discrete then the union $\bigcup\limits_{x\in\Bbb{R}}$ will turn out to be a countable disjoint union and we can use the property of measure to writing it as a summation.

Can anyone give any idea to prove the statement rigorously? Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only discetre random variable can be handled the way you have done. You have to use Fubini's Theorem to prove this result.

$P(X+Y \in B)=\int \int I_{\{(x,y): x+y \in B\}} dP_Y(y)dP_X(x)=\int P(Y \in B-x)dP_X(x)$  since $\int I_{\{(x,y): x+y \in B\}} dP_Y(y)=P(Y \in B-x)$.

Comment: Yes. I just thought about it. We have to use Fubini's theorem